# First attempt at dealing with command-line args

Tags: c#, strings, parsing

A little while ago I was fiddling with [dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection) and came up with this small WPF application that I can launch with command-line arguments.

Not only this was my first experiment with DI, it was also my first experiment with parsing command-line arguments. The result works nicely, but looking at the code today I see a number of things I would have done differently.

**What would *you* have done differently?**

Looking mainly for feedback on readability and maintainability.

---

I have an interface/class that exposes getters for all *possible* command-line arguments; the implementation's constructor uses Ninject's `InjectAttribute` to specify the required `ICommandLineArg` implementation to receive:

```
public class AutoBuildCommandLineHelper : IAutoBuildCommandLineArgs
{
    public ICommandLineArg QuietInterfaceArgument { get; private set; }
    public ICommandLineArg BuildServerArgument { get; private set; }
    public ICommandLineArg CompletionMessageArgument { get; private set; }
    public ICommandLineArg LoggingDisabledArgument { get; private set; }
    public ICommandLineArg FailureNotificationOnlyArgument { get; private set; }

    public AutoBuildCommandLineHelper([QuietInterfaceArg] ICommandLineArg quietInterfaceArg,
                                       [BuildServerArg] ICommandLineArg buildServerArg,
                                       [NoLogArg] ICommandLineArg noLogArg,
                                       [MessageArg] ICommandLineArg msgArg,
                                       [FailureNotifyArg] ICommandLineArg failArg)
    {
        QuietInterfaceArgument = quietInterfaceArg;
        BuildServerArgument = buildServerArg;
        LoggingDisabledArgument = noLogArg;
        CompletionMessageArgument = msgArg;
        FailureNotificationOnlyArgument = failArg;
    }
}
```

---

Here are a couple `ICommandLineArg` implementations:

```
public class QuietInterfaceArgument : CommandLineArgumentBase
{
    public QuietInterfaceArgument(string[] args)
        : base(args, "q", "quiet") { }
}

public class NoLoggingArgument : CommandLineArgumentBase
{
    public NoLoggingArgument(string[] args)
        : base(args, "n", "nolog") { }
}
```

As you see there's really nothing going on here - this is the base class:

```
public abstract class CommandLineArgumentBase : ICommandLineArg
{
    private readonly string[] _args;
    private const char ParamSpecifier = ':';
    private readonly char[] _switches = { '-', '/' };

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Alias { get; private set; }
    public bool MustHaveParameter { get; private set; }

    protected CommandLineArgumentBase(string[] args, string name, string alias) 
        : this(args, name, alias, false) { }

    protected CommandLineArgumentBase(string[] args, string name, string alias, bool mustHaveParam)
    {
        _args = args;
        Name = name;
        Alias = alias;
        MustHaveParameter = mustHaveParam;
    }

    public virtual string ParameterValue()
    {
        if (!IsSpecified()) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        var arg = GetArgument();

        var values = arg.Split(ParamSpecifier);
        if (MustHaveParameter && values.Length == 1) throw new InvalidOperationException();

        return values[1].TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');
    }

    private string GetArgument()
    {
        if (!IsSpecified()) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        return _args.Single(arg => new[] {Name, Alias}.Contains(TrimArgument(arg).Split(ParamSpecifier)[0]));
    }

    private string TrimArgument(string arg)
    {
        return arg.TrimStart(_switches).TrimEnd(_switches);
    }

    public bool IsSpecified()
    {
        return _args.Select(arg => arg.Split(ParamSpecifier)[0])
                    .Select(TrimArgument)
                    .Contains(Name) || _args.Any(arg => TrimArgument(arg).StartsWith(Name));
    }
}
```

---

This "thing" is used in `Program.cs` / `Main()`, like this:

```
        if (argsHelper.LoggingDisabledArgument.IsSpecified()) 
            logProvider.DisableLogging();

        if (argsHelper.QuietInterfaceArgument.IsSpecified() 
         || argsHelper.BuildServerArgument.IsSpecified())
        {
            // running with -quiet or -build command-line switches: just execute and exit.
            autoBuildApp.Execute();
        }
        else
        {
            // run with UI:
            var app = new App(autoBuildApp);
            app.Run();
        }
```

I like that arguments are strongly-typed and all I need to do to check if they're specified, is to call `.IsSpecified()` - the flipside is that to achieve this I'm passing the `args` string everywhere, so it gets "parsed" *every time*.

**Thoughts?**

Comment: Forgive me if this is a dumb question but should the `[QuietInterfaceArg]` part of `[QuietInterfaceArg] ICommandLineArg quietInterfaceArg` instead be `[QuietInterfaceArgument]`?

Comment: @JamesKhoury That still wouldn't work, attributes have to derive from `Attribute`. Which means that there has to be a type that the OP forgot to include, probably called `QuietInterfaceArgAttribute`.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't bother including the Ninject `InjectAttribute`-derived classes. Should I add them in?

Comment: @retailcoder only for those like me who are not versed in ninject-ness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Style**

1. I don't like the name `AutoBuildCommandLineHelper` for a class which implements an interface like `IAutoBuildCommandLineArgs`. I would have named it `AutoBuildCommandLineArgs`
2. You have made `ParamSpecifier` a named constant but not the quotes you strip of the parameter value.

**Possible Bugs**

1. If I read `IsSpecified()` correctly then it accepts arguments starting with `Name`. Given that `Name` seems to be the one letter abbreviation this means if I specify an invalid argument which happens to start with a letter of a valid argument then `IsSpecified()` will return true.
2. If you call `ParameterValue()` on an argument which does not have (i.e. doesn't require) a parameter it will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` as `values` will only have 1 entry

**Design**

When you want to add a new command line option you have to do 5 or 6 things:

1. Add a new class representing the new option
2. Register that class with the IoC container (this could possibly happen automagically depending on the container used)
3. Add a new property to `IAutoBuildCommandLineArgs`
4. Add a new property to `AutoBuildCommandLineHelper`
5. Add a new property to `AutoBuildCommandLineHelper` constructor
6. Add a new assignment in `AutoBuildCommandLineHelper` constructor to copy parameter into property

Seems a bit involved. I hacked together an alternative version which should fit DI just nicely:

```
public enum Option
{
    NoLog,
    Quiet,
    Server,
    LogLevel,
    Help,
}

public interface ICommandLineOptions
{
    bool Has(Option option);
    string ValueOf(Option option);
}

public class CommandLineOptions : ICommandLineOptions
{
    private class CommandLineOption
    {
        public CommandLineOption(Option type, string shortKey, string longKey, string description, bool requiresParam)
        {
            Type = type;
            Short = shortKey;
            Long = longKey;
            Description = description;
            RequiresParam = requiresParam; 
        }

        public readonly Option Type;
        public readonly string Short;
        public readonly string Long;
        public readonly string Description;
        public readonly bool RequiresParam;
    }

    private static readonly List<CommandLineOption> _AllOptions = 
        new List<CommandLineOption>
        {
            new CommandLineOption(Option.NoLog,     "n", "nolog",    "Don't log",          false),
            new CommandLineOption(Option.Quiet,     "q", "quiet",    "Run quietly",        false),
            new CommandLineOption(Option.Server,    "s", "server",   "Run in server mode", false),
            new CommandLineOption(Option.LogLevel, "ll", "loglevel", "Set log level",      true),
            new CommandLineOption(Option.Help,      "?", "help",     "Print help",         false),
        };

    private static const char _ParamSpecifier = ':';
    private static readonly char[] _Switches = { '-', '/' };
    private static readonly char[] _Quotes = { '"', '\'' };

    private Dictionary<Option, string> _AvailableOptions = new Dictionary<Option, string>();

    public CommandLineOptions(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var arg in args.Select(a => a.Trim(_Switches)))
        {
            var parts = arg.Split(new char[] {_ParamSpecifier }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var option = _AllOptions.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Short == parts.First().ToLower() || o.Long == parts.First().ToLower());
            if (option == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unknown command line option {0}", arg));
            if (option.RequiresParam && parts.Length == 1)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Command line option {0} is missing required parameter", arg));
            _AvailableOptions[option.Type] = option.RequiresParam ? parts.Last().Trim(_Quotes) : "";
        }
    }

    public bool Has(Option option)
    {
        return _AvailableOptions.ContainsKey(option);
    }

    public string ValueOf(Option option)
    {
        string value;
        if (!_AvailableOptions.TryGetValue(option, out value))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Option {0} not present", option));
        return value;
    }
}
```

When you want to add a new option you have to do 2 things:

1. Add a new entry to the `enum`
2. Add a new entry to the `_AllOptions` dictionary

From a DI perspective anything which needs access to the options just depends on `ICommandLineOptions`.

If you wanted to get real fancy you could make `CommandLineOption` public, add an interface `ICommandLineOption` for it and make `CommandLineOptions` take a dependency on a collection of `ICommandLineOption`s. Then you could register all the options you want to support in the container rather than hard coding them in `CommandLineOptions`.

Answer (score 3):

### Default command line switches

It is recommended that tools specify the following standard switches. You should always define these. Also, on error, output the error and the help text.

```
- help (--help -h -?)
- about (--version -!)
```

---

### Maintainability

The fact your arguments include the keywords used for parsing is a breach of **Single Responsibility**. I would extract all lexing in a seperate class behind some interface. This way, you can make different lexers for Posix, DOS, Windows, Google style.

---

### Readability

Get rid of the postfix `-Argument` in your property names. It's redundant and verbose.

---

### Command line parsing

Command line parsing is an art. A good command line parser is able to parse both readable and administrative command lines, different styles, grammars, literals, escape sequences.

There are different formatting styles.

[Google dev style](https://developers.google.com/style/code-syntax)

```
tool --get-logs --in c:\data\in\ -quiet
```

[POSIX short style](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html)

```
tool-gq-ic:\data\in\
```

[Windows/DOS style](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm)

```
tool /gq /i c:\data\in\
```

---

### Design Restrictions

I don't know your intend, but if you want to comply to at least the aforementioned command line styles, you have restricted yourself.

You have hardcoded your delimiters. This means you are only compliant to your own standards, not universal ones. For instance, other `ParamSpecifier` that could have been allowed are `'='`, `','` and even a *blank space* in the right context. Other `_switches` include the Posix long-option `'--'`.

> ```
>  private const char ParamSpecifier = ':';
>  private readonly char[] _switches = { '-', '/' };
> ```

Command switches could have `0..*` arguments. However, you limit this to `0..1`.

> `public bool MustHaveParameter { get; private set; }`

You perform a naive switch-value split. This does not take into account escaped delimiters or file paths.

> `var values = arg.Split(ParamSpecifier);`

```
- -a:literal\:value
- -a:literal":"value
- -a:c:\temp\
```

Quoted literals should not be restricted to the start and end of a string, but could also be inline.

> `return values[1].TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');`

---

Comment: Blast from the past! Nice review. I've since made it a habit to download a nuget package for handling command-line args whenever I need them =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Good thinking not to reinvent the wheel for command line parsing. It could get you sucked into the rabbit hole :-p